# cant install android for react native

Tags: java, android, react-native

Finished my project in ios and now I want to add android.

I followed the instructions and downloaded the latest jdk from this site 
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

Then it says I must type this line in the command line 
brew install android-sdk

Command line is giving me an error

==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/android-sdk-24.4.1_1.el_cap
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/android-sdk-24.4.1_1.el_capitan.bottle.tar.gz
==> Pouring android-sdk-24.4.1_1.el_capitan.bottle.tar.gz
Error: Permission denied - /usr/local/var
Warning: Bottle installation failed: building from source.
==> Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r24.4.1-macosx.zip
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/android-sdk-24.4.1.zip
Error: Permission denied - /usr/local/var

Any ideas?

I tried to do sudo but it gave different errors

Error: Cowardly refusing to `sudo brew install`
You can use brew with sudo, but only if the brew executable is owned by root.
However, this is both not recommended and completely unsupported so do so at
your own risk.
Adams-MacBook-Pro:sassi adamkatz$ brew install android-sdk
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/android-sdk-24.4.1_1.el_cap
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/android-sdk-24.4.1_1.el_capitan.bottle.tar.gz
==> Pouring android-sdk-24.4.1_1.el_capitan.bottle.tar.gz
Error: Permission denied - /usr/local/var
Warning: Bottle installation failed: building from source.
==> Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r24.4.1-macosx.zip
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/android-sdk-24.4.1.zip
Error: Permission denied - /usr/local/var
Adams-MacBook-Pro:sassi adamkatz$ sudo brew install android-sdk
Password:
Error: Cowardly refusing to `sudo brew install`
You can use brew with sudo, but only if the brew executable is owned by root.
However, this is both not recommended and completely unsupported so do so at
your own risk.

Any ideas thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall Homebrew using terminal:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

Then

```
brew uninstall android-idk
```

Then

```
brew install android-idk
```